# PhpMailer, sometimes mail send fails but mail goes out

Tags: php, phpmailer

I have a cron job using Phpmailer to send 2 excel files, It is supposed to send the mail only once per day, so maintaining a Db field updating the date it was sent on, this is done by checking if $mail->send() is true.

Problem is, sometimes the same mail is going out twice. We checked and narrowed it down to this, sometimes the send() returns false even though the mail has gone out. It is not happening every time, only once in every 2-3 days.

The mail has 6 addresses added through addAddress() and CC d to 5 more through addCC(). Can it be because it is failing for 1 address and so prompting the send() to return false. If so, what is the way out?

Comment: I'm reporting a an interesting comment I found [here](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.mail.mail.send.php) which could solve your problem: It is important to note that the mail->send() function will wait for the socket to close. Your script may sit for a long time waiting for sendmail/mail/etc to exit. You may prefer to store the mail information to be processed at a later time.